# Thumb Drive 8GB: slow write rate

Tags: performance, usb-flash-drive, sd-card, data-transfer, compact-flash

I've just benchmarked some memory devices using [GNOME Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks) and [F3](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here's a summary:

| **Device** | **Size** | **Avg Write** | **Min Write** | **Max Write** | **Chart** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Compact Flash | 64 MB | 1.1 MB/s | 1.1 MB/s | 1.1 MB/s | [benchmark 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QehND.jpg) |
| Compact Flash | 130 MB | 7.3 MB/s | 7.2 MB/s | 7.4 MB/s | [benchmark 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWLSy.jpg) |
| General USB | 2 GB | 5.0 MB/s | 4.0 MB/s | 6.5 MB/s | [benchmark 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0f3s.jpg) |
| SD Card | 2 GB | 4.7 MB/s | 3.5 MB/s | 5.0 MB/s | [benchmark 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFwmJ.jpg) |
| SD Card | 4 GB | 3.2 MB/s | 2.0 MB/s | 4.5 MB/s | [benchmark 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV6Vf.jpg) |
| Thumb Drive | 8 GB | 971 KB/s | 0 | 14 MB/s | [benchmark 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoV08.jpg) |

Notice that the write rate of the Thumb Drive (SanDisk Cruzer Blade) is the worst, even though this device is the newest.
However, AFAIR, this thumb drive wasn't that slow just a little while ago.

To check what was going on, I've teardown it. Unfortunately, I could not find any explanation:
[Teardown of SanDisk Cruzer Blade 8GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WMJx.jpg)

#### Question

Why the write rate of this Thumb Drive is getting so slow?

Comment: Compare: http://www.cdrlabs.com/reviews/sandisk-cruzer-blade-usb-flash-drive/performance-and-conclusion.html It may be overheating (does it feel hot?)

Comment: Could be you got a fake drive.

Comment: I think @Mokubai is right. I've myself had some SanDisk's, and all of them had a green-board with a black storage, something like this: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS8QU77md53yIA8UjzU7VxQbVw7iWJCk887PQ&usqp=CAU  However while surfing the internet for that image, I found that the chip you had inside it resembles that to SanDisk Cruzer Fit 's, : https://andrewbirkel.com/wp-content/gallery/usb-stick/thumbs/thumbs_2013-06-08-12-04-04.jpg I don't know why would anyone do that, but that large space inside your pendrive's case doesn't makes sense either.

Comment: @Gantendo Great review. I've searched everywhere for something like this but couldn't find. +1

Comment: @Gantendo > "It may be overheating (does it feel hot?)" Yes, it gets hot. To support even more that, notice that it starts writing at reasonable speeds then, after a while (maybe bc it overheats), its performance drops really low.

Comment: @Gantendo Curiously, I have already tried to keep it cool with some "MacGyver hacks" but it didn't worked, ie, the write speed were still very slow. Maybe the hacks were not that good, I'm not sure ...

Comment: @Mokubai > "Could be you got a fake drive." Any idea how can I check that?

Comment: @SaaranshGarg > "that large space inside your pendrive's case doesn't makes sense either." Agree. Indeed it is very weird.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3d5q4CwxNc and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4PbMkIr5yA

Comment: @Gantendo > "[SanDisk Cruzer Blade 32GB Flash Drive - Original/Clone/Fake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3d5q4CwxNc)" According to that source of yours, the 2nd thumb drive (smallest chip), is the original. Therefore, do you agree mine is an original SanDisk?

Comment: @JeronBaffom It seems likely. https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/ #5 ChipGenius may be of help.

Comment: @Gantendo > "It seems likely." I'm reading the comments of such video. It seems that both thumb drives are actually fake ones. However, I'm not an expert to be sure about that.

Comment: @Gantendo > "#5 ChipGenius may be of help." This software requires Windows. I'm gonna need a while to arrange that.

Comment: @Gantendo > "#5 ChipGenius may be of help." Currently I'm using [f3 - Fight Flash Fraud](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which was even recommended somewhere in the comment section.

Comment: So, any update, results etc?

Comment: @SaaranshGarg > "So, any update, results etc?" Unfortunately, no. For now, the best speculation is that somehow the hardware is deteriorating (overheat?) which is slowing down the write speed.